# VB.NET External EXE Embedded

Tags: c#, vb.net

I know this seems to be a popular topic but I am having trouble embedding an external program (Not VB related) into my VB.NET project, I can get notepad to embed correctly but for the life of me am unable to get this other program to embed, it does load and come up correctly though.

Here is what I have.

At the very least I would like to be able to get this to automatically open the external EXE and then maybe dock it inside my project or even just being able to hit my `button1`, have the external come up and then dock into my project. But I would really like to just get it embedded lol, I am extremely new to all this so please go easy on me :3

PS : I have tried adding the application as an Embedded Resource.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
    Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
    Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Run Notepad application inside Panel1 control
        Dim proc As Process
        proc = Process.Start("LLO.exe")
        proc.WaitForInputIdle()
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.Panel1.Handle)
        SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: When you think it works for notepad is it running the embedded notepad.exe or just the general notepad.exe available in the windows folder of the system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the executable, for example: `proc = Process.Start("C:\Path\To\LLO.exe")`. Or make sure the executable is in the same folder as your program.